# How to use Scrapy to find out the number of classes with the same name?

Tags: python, html, dom, scrapy, css-selectors

How to use Scrapy to find out the number of classes with the word "on" in the class name?

```html
<div class="listing item-rating" style="display: block;">
  <img src="/Content/images/spacer.gif" class="star-left on">
  <img src="/Content/images/spacer.gif" class="star-right on">  
  <img src="/Content/images/spacer.gif" class="star-left on">
  <img src="/Content/images/spacer.gif" class="star-right of">  
  <img src="/Content/images/spacer.gif" class="star-left of">
  <img src="/Content/images/spacer.gif" class="star-left of">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

- `response.xpath('//*[has-class("on")]')` gives you the selector (all classes that have 'on')
- `len(response.xpath('//*[has-class("on")]'))` gives you the length - in this case the number of classes